# ffmpeg library does not work from path but directly

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I want to add a watermark to a video.

I'm trying with windows 10 and ffmpeg library

The command I am using.

```
ffmpeg -i example.mp4 -i watermark.png  -filter_complex "overlay=0-0+0:main_h-overlay_h-0+0" watermark.mp4
```

When I use it this way accesing the path I get this error:

[image]

But when I execute it not from path but opening cmd right on the executable folder it works fine

I did some research and couldn't find the answers I was looking for.

Why does this happen? I can´t understand really

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log indicates that your `ffmpeg` is very old. The built-in FFmpeg AAC encoder has not been considered experimental since 2015.

There is certainly an old `ffmpeg.exe` somewhere in your `PATH`.

[Download](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) a modern version of `ffmpeg` and place it somewhere in your `PATH` so it takes precedence over the rogue, old version, or search for the old `ffmpeg.exe` and delete it.

Comment: Hey :-) I have the version 4.2.3 install and it works but if I access the bin from the system path that error appears. This does not happen when I access the bin from exact location: like C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-4.2.3-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe

Comment: @ÁngelBarrios You have multiple version installed. Locate the rogue `ffmpeg.exe`.

Comment: Yes, it worked but I don't understand very much. I added C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-4.2.3-win64-static\bin to my user path. I just removed it and then it goes. I don't think this lib was installed before. How could I have multiple versions?

Comment: @ÁngelBarrios Not sure, but there is/was certainly an old one in your `PATH` somewhere. Maybe some other program included it.